# How should I structure a table that requires numerous aggregations?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm creating a table called `monthly_revenue`, which will store columns displayed in a monthly revenue report csv. Each row contains revenue data for a month and year. There are about 60 columns of revenue data. The data is aggregated from eight other tables. For example, `monthly_revenue` contains the following columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS monthly_revenue (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    pkg_revenue DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    reseller_revenue DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    pkg_revenue DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    setup_amount DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    support_amount DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    promo_credit DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
    federal_fee DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    total_monthly_revenue DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
);
```

The column `monthly_revenue.pkg_revenue` equals the sum of two other aggregations for the month and year: `((SUM(invoices.pkg_cost)) + (SUM(pkg_archive.pkg_cost)))`

Some columns aggregate multiple other columns in `monthly_revenue`. For example, the column `monthly_revenue.total_monthly_revenue` equals `SUM(pkg_revenue + reseller_revenue + setup_amount + support_amount - promo_credit - federal_fee)`

My current plan is to create a table called `monthly_revenue_variables`, which will store individual variables that are aggregated in columns of `monthly_revenue`. I will use functions that have a month and year as arguments to aggregate columns like `monthly_revenue_variables.pkg_revenue`, which can then be aggregated in `monthly_revenue.total_monthly_revenue` along with the five other columns in `monthly_revenue_variables`.

I dislike that my current plan redundantly stores data; `monthly_revenue.pkg_revenue` and `monthly_revenue_variables.pkg_revenue` would contain the exact same values for a given month and year. However, I like that `monthly_revenue_variables` will flatten my sql code, per se, such that I'm not conducting multiple nested aggregations in columns like `monthly_revenue.total_monthly_revenue`.

Alternatively, I am considering using a series of common table expressions (CTEs) in the place of `monthly_revenue_variables`.

I am relatively new to sql, so any suggestions for how to structure the creation and population of `monthly_revenue` are welcome!

Comment: I agree with you that storing data redundantly is not satisfying. You can create a view instead of a table to aggregate various data from various tables, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html

Comment: Another alternative would be a [Materialized View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html). It offers the advantage of a table, and can be indexed. The downside is the data may be 'stale' as it will only be as current as the last update. But if needed for only  aggregating monthly values or even month to date daily should be satisfactory.